# convert .mov video to .mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, format, macos-sierra

I am trying to convert a .mov video to .mp4 with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Desktop/Sample.mov ~/Desktop/Sample.mp4
```

This doesn't work though, and when I try to open the produced video in quicktime it tells me that the file is either corrupted or in a format quicktime doesn't understand.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Use handbrake for MAC

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To convert videos, I like to use handbrake. You can find it here: https://handbrake.fr/ I use it on Linux but it should work well on MAC too.

For HandBrake:

```
handbrakecli -i {in-video}.mov -e x264 -E facc -o {out-video}.mp4
```

For ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i {in-video}.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec aac {out-video}.mp4
```

Comment: Handbrake worked. The ffmpeg command doesn't.

Comment: ffmpeg worked great as above for me

Answer (score 26):

## Copy

You can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) if the MOV file contains video and audio that is compatible with MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -movflags +faststart  output.mp4
```

- Stream copy (`-c copy`) is like a "copy and paste" so the quality is preserved and the process is fast.
- `-movflags +faststart` makes an output file that usable for HTML5 streaming, for example, putting all the necessary info to begin playback at the start of the file.  If you only care about local desktop usage, you can leave that out.
- Video formats compatible with MP4 include: H.264, H.265/HEVC, AV1 (new format, so not universally supported), MPEG-4 (old format, not supported in HTML5).
- Audio formats compatible with MP4 include: AAC, MP3 (playback support depends on player), Opus (new format, so not universally supported).

## Encode

This will convert the MOV to H.264 video and AAC audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- `-c:v libx264` choose encoder libx264 to output H.264 video.
- `-c:a aac` choose encoder aac to output AAC audio.
- `-vf format=yuv420p` chooses YUV 4:2:0 *pixel format*. libx264 supports many pixel formats and by default will choose a pixel format that most resembles the input. But not all pixel formats are supported by all players. `yuv420p` is the most compatible and universally supported.
- `-movflags +faststart` same as the *Web Optimized* option in Handbrake. After encoding completes it moves a chunk of info from the end of file to the beginning so it can start playing faster when viewing via download.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) and [FFmpeg Wiki: AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) for more info, including CPU time vs. quality vs. bitrate settings.  (x264's default is `-preset medium -crf 23`)

Comment: You can use `-movflags +faststart` with `-c copy` as well.  It's just as useful / useless either way, depending on what you want to do with the file.  (Allows the file to be streamed, e.g. from a web server.)  Also, `-c:a aac` is a low quality encoder; `libfaac` is better.  Or maybe you can keep the original audio and just transcode the video, e.g. for bitrate or codec reasons, like `-c:v libx264 -c:a copy`.

Comment: Also, future readers that want to transcode should have a look at your FFmpeg wiki links for quality vs. encode-time vs. bitrate settings, like `-preset slower` to spend more CPU time to improve the quality per bitrate tradeoff. Very worth it for encode once, stream many times.  And `-crf 23` being the default, `-crf 26` to quantize more (smaller file), `-crf 20` or so to quantize less (higher quality).

Comment: I get this error when I ran the first ffmpeg command:

`[mp4 @ 0x55c4fbbfae40] Could not find tag for codec prores in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- `

Comment: @PeterCordes [really](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777823/543873)???

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for the correction, **I was mixing up `libfaac` (even worse than `aac`) with `libfdk_aac` (significantly better)**.  That link confirms `-c:a aac` is still only "fairly good" quality per bitrate, vs. `fdk_aac` being "excellent", so it's still relatively poor compared to good encoders, or to other codecs like Opus.  (It's really too bad it's still not easy to use Opus audio with MP4 containers, instead being stuck with AAC which is burdened by proprietary encoders which still don't do as well as the free libopus.  For my own use, if xcoding audio I use `-c:a libopus -b:a 80k`)